# Why we using sip protocol with voip?

Tags: streaming, media, sip, voip, rtp

What is the purpose for using sip with VOIP ? is it just to know the remote ip address ?

If i know (by server) the remote IP address ,then established a direct TCP socket connection for call negotiation, and send the media over RTP protocol ,so am i still need sip protocol ? or how can sip help me here?

Answer (score 2):

The Session Initiation Protocol does rather a lot more than find out a remote IP address/port/transport triple.

It lets two parties

- negotiate the media streams (including codecs and transports) and
- establish commonly understood extensions to the protocol.

It also describes how to build scalable infrastructure (proxies, using SRV and NAPTR records, back to back user agents), location services and a host of other details that go into making a voice (or any other kind of) call to arbitrary third parties.

Answer (score 1):

then you have implemented a sip alternative. sip (session instanciation protocol) does just control the "phone call". if you want to do that on your own, why not? the only problem would be that there are many sip clients and just one (or few) clients using your protocol.

Comment: I want to implement that as my own application ,clients can call each others through it . like Skype.

Comment: sure, but like skype, then all users are forced to use your application, and will hate you for that, because you'll never be able to support all platforms they want to use. but yes, in general, nobody's gonna stop you from doing that.

Answer (score 1):

[SIP](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt) allocates a IP:port to a voip call. The RTP flows (one for each direction) will then use this IP:port as a destination address. If you have only one static RTP flow to send to your server, it may be useful and ok to do what you said.

Otherwise, if there are **many clients**, or if your **system has to change a lot**, it's better to use a polished protocol which will dynamically allocate ports and establish your sessions.

Comment: I do not want a sip server register, i just need two clients call each other through my application ,the main problem here is remote ip/port , so i get it by my http server .then the two clients establish a two peer to peer RTP connection .when one of them press cancel button a message sent to other client throught TCP telling him to cancel the connection .so why to use sip if i can do that? does sip give some kind of performance?

Comment: No, it's not about performance, sip is only a session establishment protocol. Be careful with port management though, you will have to handle stuff like multiple calls going to a single IP, NATs etc. 
However, it is recommended to use UDP to transport real time flows like voip, TCP will introduce jitter and voice deformations.

Comment: actually, i'd recommend doing both: first try udp with upnp if firewall gets in the way, then (if even upnp didn't get us the port opened) fallback to tcp. there are still stupid routers out there, which would block our incoming stream, especcially with random ports.(that's why I wasn't able to use SIP for years -_-)

Answer (score 0):

nobody forces you to implement a standard.

e.g. why do you implement the media stream in RTP? most likely because you already have code that "talks" RTP (e.g. a library, or a raedymade application).

the nice thing about standards is, that it will work "out-of-the-box" with all other applications implementing the same standard.

if it is an *open* standard, there's another nice thing: other people have already spent a lot of brain power into getting the implementation right. you don't need to fall into the same problems.